# FlutterBloc StreamController - Stream has already been listened to

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have the following **'View Items'** widget:

```html
class _ViewItems extends State<ViewItems> {

  Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
    return Scaffold(
      body: BlocBuilder<MyBloc, MyBlocState>(
         builder: (context, state){
            StreamBuilder<List<String>>(
              stream: state.stream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) { }// building some UI
            )
         }
      ) 
    );
  }
}
```

And here's my Bloc:

```html
class MyBloc extends Bloc<MyBlocEvent, MyBlocState> {

  List<String> _items = [];
  final StreamController<List<String>> _streamController = StreamController();

  Stream<List<String>> get stream => _streamController.stream;

  MyBloc() : super(const MyBlocStateInitialize()) {
    _streamController.add(_items);

    on<MyBlocEventInitialize>(
      (event, emit) {
        _items = await objectBox.getItems().expand((element) => element).toList();; // grabbing data from local db
        _streamController.add(_items);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

However, when I use `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(someRoute)`, then go back to **'View Items'** I get the following error:

```
StateError (Bad state: Cannot add event while adding a stream)
```

and sometimes:

```
StateError (Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.)
```

even though I dispose my controller..
Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Stream should not be exposed this way, that makes not sense in my opinion. You should rather listen for stream changes inside bloc and emit specific events to refresh state on new data received from database. You can use `emit.onEach()` or `emit.forEach()` methods to emit events on stream change.

UI layer should listen for events and refresh themself if required. Don't expose or listen stream directly. You can look at flutter bloc examples on Github to get more info: https://github.com/felangel/bloc/tree/master/examples/flutter_bloc_with_stream

Comment: I followed your instructions (moved the streamController into the Bloc, and only exposing a getter. However, the code inside the link you sent isn't clear to me: How do I access the stream inside the bloc? I can't think of any other way other than using context.watch.

Comment: Your case is covered in example app I linked, have you checked it?

Comment: Yes. It took me a while to understand the code as it's the first time I encounter emite.forEach, and I couldn't find any StreamController which had me confused.

Comment: `I couldn't find any StreamController which had me confused.` - you should look what paremeter takes `emit.forEach`. You need to provide you stream and callback method to be called on stream change/error. In callback method you can either emit new state or add event to notify ui